# clipping text in python/tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to draw text on a tkinter canvas, within a previously drawn rectangle. I want to clip the text to be drawn entirely within the rectangle, hopefully by just specifying a maximum allowed width. Is there a straightforward way to do this in tkinter? If not, could I be using something else that would make it easier? Thanks

EDIT: "clipping" in a graphics sense, that is, draw the object (the string) as if it has enough room to be displayed in full, but only draw the portion of the object that is in the specified bounds, like this:
[alt text http://garblesnarky.net/images/pythontextclip.png](http://garblesnarky.net/images/pythontextclip.png)

Comment: Then I don't think that's doable using python binding :( sorry.

Answer (score 3):

something along the lines of:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
c.pack()
c.create_rectangle(50,50,91,67, outline='blue')
t = Label(c, text="Hello John, Michael, Eric, ...", anchor='w')
c.create_window(51, 51, width=40, height=15, window=t, anchor='nw')
root.mainloop()
```

perhaps you could even use an Entry widget rather than a Label

this link could be of considerable interest:
http://effbot.org/zone/editing-canvas-text-items.htm

Comment: Wow, thanks, but I can't even remember what I was trying to do when I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Small patch over  [noob oddy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123463/clipping-text-in-python-tkinter/6692378#6692378) (use a slider to illustrate the clipping actually works).

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=300, height=100)
c.pack()
r = c.create_rectangle(50,50,91,67, outline='blue')
t = Label(c, text="Hello John, Michael, Eric, ...", anchor='w')
clip = c.create_window(51, 51, height=15, window=t, anchor='nw')

def update_clipping(new_width):
    x,y,w,h = c.coords(r)
    c.coords(r,x,y,x+int(new_width)+1,h)
    c.itemconfig(clip,width=new_width)

s = Scale(root,from_=10, to=200,  orient=HORIZONTAL, command=update_clipping)
s.pack()

root.mainloop()
```